# Unable to connect to mongo on remote server

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, iptables, ubuntu-server

I have installed mongo on machine1(`Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS server`) in my local network. I have also opened the port `27017` as mentioned in [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/#traffic-to-and-from-mongod-instances) guide using following commands:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 27017 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT  -p tcp --source-port 27017 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Current rules are (`iptables -L`):

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:27017 state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:27017 state ESTABLISHED
```

---

But I am not able to connect to this port from machine2 (in the same network):

```
$ mongo --host 192.168.0.108
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.4
connecting to: 192.168.0.108:27017/test
2016-01-23T18:02:14.848+0530 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 192.168.0.108:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2016-01-23T18:02:14.850+0530 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 192.168.0.108:27017 (192.168.0.108), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181
exception: connect failed
```

I also tried checking if port is opened or not:

```
$ nc -v 192.168.0.108 27017
nc: connectx to 192.168.0.108 port 27017 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

I am not sure what I am missing. Must be some silly mistake as I am setting up mongo for the first time. Pls help.

**Update (for the doubts raised in current answers)**

1. Yeah its running. I am able to connect to mongo form the same machine but not from the other machine. The daemon is running: `$ service mongod status mongod start/running, process 31205` and the port is 27017 `$ sudo netstat -tulpn |grep 27017 tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:27017 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 31205/mongod`
2. I changed the `bind_ip` to `0.0.0.0` and restarted mongo. Still the same error is coming.

**Mongo logs**:

```
$ cat /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
2016-01-23T16:28:13.155+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=31205 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=dexter
2016-01-23T16:28:13.156+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.1
2016-01-23T16:28:13.156+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a14d55980c2cdc565d4704a7e3ad37e4e535c1b2
2016-01-23T16:28:13.156+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
2016-01-23T16:28:13.156+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-01-23T16:28:13.156+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-01-23T16:28:13.156+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-01-23T16:28:13.156+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1404
2016-01-23T16:28:13.156+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-01-23T16:28:13.156+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-01-23T16:28:13.156+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2016-01-23T16:28:13.173+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-01-23T16:28:14.444+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-01-23T16:28:14.444+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-01-23T16:28:14.444+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-01-23T16:28:14.444+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-01-23T16:28:14.444+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-01-23T16:28:14.444+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-01-23T16:28:14.444+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-01-23T16:28:14.444+0530 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data'
2016-01-23T16:28:14.444+0530 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2016-01-23T16:28:14.949+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-01-23T16:38:37.046+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:37032 #1 (1 connection now open)
2016-01-23T16:39:31.447+0530 I NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:37032 (0 connections now open)
2016-01-23T16:49:24.240+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:37033 #2 (1 connection now open)
2016-01-23T16:49:38.249+0530 I NETWORK  [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:37033 (0 connections now open)
2016-01-23T16:51:51.707+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:37034 #3 (1 connection now open)
2016-01-23T16:51:55.785+0530 I NETWORK  [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:37034 (0 connections now open)
2016-01-23T17:32:15.546+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:37036 #4 (1 connection now open)
2016-01-23T17:32:21.180+0530 I NETWORK  [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:37036 (0 connections now open)
2016-01-23T18:11:57.885+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:37037 #5 (1 connection now open)
2016-01-23T18:29:55.365+0530 I NETWORK  [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:37037 (0 connections now open)
```

Comment: Would it be possible to add mongod server logs somewhere ? Initial 100 lines would be enough.

Comment: @nobody Updated the mongo logs

Comment: Hope you already got clue from logs.

Comment: Yeah got the issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/35063229/742173

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue was `bindIp` didn't change. There was some issue in restarting mongo from my side.

The habit should be to verify if the bindIp actually changed or not. (using `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 27017`)

Comment: How would bindIp change? I manually added the remote address to `mongodb.conf` under bindIp but still not able to connect

Comment: Commenting ```bindIp``` did not work. I had to change it to ```0.0.0.0```

Answer (score 31):

make sure that mongodb daemon is running, and listening on 0.0.0.0, but not 127.0.0.1 port

for example, for my local mongodb, it has this config:

```
[vodolaz095@steel ~]$ cat /etc/mongod.conf 
##
### Basic Defaults
##

# Comma separated list of ip addresses to listen on (all local ips by default)
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1

# Specify port number (27017 by default)
#port = 27017
```

for mongodb server to listen for remote connections, you can change

```
# Comma separated list of ip addresses to listen on (all local ips by default)
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I changed the `bind_ip` and restarted mongo. Still the same error is coming.

Comment: is firewall opened? what linux distro is used? is SELINUX enabled? is there any info in mongodb logs?

Comment: What you mean by firewall opened? I don't know much about firewall. I just added the rules in `iptables`. Distro: `$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"`

There is nothing in logs

Comment: so the firewall rules (`iptables -l`) looks ok, port is correct, listening address (`bind_ip` in config), and i'm more familiar with RPM based distros instead of DEB based ones to be able to help. So i think you can post this question on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Yes exactly the mongo db should eb running at 0.0.0.0

Comment: My problem was, I can `telnet` any port except mongo port. I changed `bind_ip` to `0.0.0.0` and it was fixed.

Answer (score 26):

With mongoDB server version 3.6.4, Ubuntu 16.4.4 I solved this by setting the net section in /etc/mongod.conf like this:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIpAll: true
#  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 6):

I have tried a different way to solve this issue. I have changed the config file from

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
#port = 27017
```

to

```
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
#port = 27017
```

Hope it helps. Happy coding ;)

Comment: Helped like charm, but don't u think this can be vulnerable. I tied putting my instance IP but was not able to remote connect any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a  daemon running on your machine1 which listen to port 27017. We were getting the same error and found that daemon was not running.

Comment: Yeah its running. I am able to connect to mongo form the same machine but not from the other machine. The daemon is running: 
`$ service mongod status
mongod start/running, process 31205`
and the port is 27017
`$ sudo netstat -tulpn |grep 27017
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31205/mongod`